# If $\partial A$ is bounded, then $A$ is bounded

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$,  $A \neq \emptyset$. 
If $\partial A$ is bounded, then $A$ is bounded, is it true?

Comment: You should write $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 9):

It is not true. Just consider $A=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Or $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B$ for any bounded set $B$. +1 for you.

Comment: Sure @MPW, you are correct